# linklist using next prev top and bottom pointers

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list

You are given a node structure having four different types of pointer to keep track of previous, next, top and bottom nodes. Data is saved in data portion of the node.
You are required to create a linked list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koOpY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read up on [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and then make an attempt at solving this problem yourself. We'll be able to help you much better if you ask questions about an attempt.

Comment: Putting it more bluntly, Stack Overflow is not a service for solving your homework for you.